# Change color from checkbox text

Tags: jquery, html

```
<P><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="nombre" VALUE="Si"> bla bla <BR></P>
```

This is my code, and I want to change the color from the text `bla bla`. What I have done is `$("p").css('color','red');` but the problem is that if I add some next text using the `before()` or `after()` jQuery methods it also obtains the red color. Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Comment: You can only set the colour of an entire element, this is why adding new text also receives the red colour. A workaround would be to put the new text inside a different element, such as a `span`, and apply CSS to change the text colour of just that span

Comment: You can wrap _bla bla_ in span and then change its color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add wrapper span or div whatever suits you for "bla bla". Actually `$("p").css('color','red');` will assign color property on entire `<p>` element

HTML

```
<P><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="nombre" VALUE="Si">
<span class="demo-class">bla bla<span> <BR></P>
```

Jquery

```
$("p .demo-class").css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline:

```
<P>         
    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="nombre" VALUE="Si"><span style="color: red"> bla bla </span><BR>     
</P>
```

Take a look at http://w3schools.com, They have a good explaination on basic mechanics for CSS/HTML